# Is there such thing as a Bipolar Wall-wart?

Tags: ac, ul, wall-wart, power-supply

Looking for a UL approved device that gives +9V and -9V from the 120VAC wall.
I need the +/-9V to power a circuit and I don't want to make an extra PCB.
My alternative is to have two 9V wall warts but who wants to plug things in twice? What happens when the end user loses one of the chargers?

EDIT: where can I buy one? I need to pull at least 2A from either side

Comment: yes, it is available ... keep looking ... your last two questions are not answerable and also pointless

Comment: Use an 18V wall wart or even a 19V laptop PSU and make a virtual 0V halfway between its supply rails.

Comment: I have a wall-wart (that I bought surplus for $1) that supplies +/- 12 VDC and +/- 5 VDC. (Actually, I bought up 5 of them. They used a nice big transformer.) Biggest "wall-wart" I ever did see!

Comment: You could make +/-9 from the more common +/-12v power supplies using some cheap linear regulators.  Would also be beneficial for reducing noise.

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you for your suggestion. I do have linear regulators somewhere down stream, I just wanted the raw +/- supplies without having two physical devices to plug in to the wall.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That only works if I am not pulling any high current otherwise ohms Law won't be too happy with me and the virtual ground is going to deviate all over the place

Comment: That depends how you drive it. For example, an audio power amplifier should be good for a few amps...

Comment: just gang two 9vdc together in series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, I just found one [GP50A13D-R1B](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mean-well-usa-inc/GP50A13D-R1B/1866-1832-ND/7703343)

Comment: I am glad you told me what I didn't know that I didn't know. The one you found is good because (1) it is a wall wart and therefore spacing saving, (2) no need to plug twice, therefore less trouble making and shooting. (3) The MW US is a very good brand.  I am a huge friend of it.

Answer (score 1):

There probably is, but the way bipolar rails are done in most situations is an AC step down transformer, then you rectify it on the board and regulate it. (but that requires an extra board). There are plenty of power supplies that output ±9V available.